Youtube advanced search: Thumbnail, specific duration, and more
I'm trying to find an important YouTube video that I want to watch, which I came across while scrolling on mobile. (could not remember what the video is about, although if I see it I will know it)
Is there a website that allows you to search for a video by  its thumbnail text? (the video I am searching for has the text
Full
Documentary

shown in its left bottom corner)

Additionally it would be great if I can filter the results by duration. (the video I am searching for is either 1:20:00 long or up to 1:29:59)

Also, another option is to  minus-search by the its title text (the video I am searching for does not have the text "full" nor "documentary" in its title)


